# ¿Como borrar puntero a una instancia? (este puntero se encuentra alojado en un vector de punteros)

Tags: c++, array, class

imaginemos que tenemos dos clases A y B:

- desde la clase A en private creo un vector de punteros a instancias de B
  `vector <B*> punt;`

¿Como se añadirían punteros a instancias de B en ese vector?
¿Como se eliminarían esos punteros del vector? ¿Como un vector normal?

```
   B *newB=new B(name); // suponiendo que tienes un constructor que asigna el nombre
   punt.push_back(newB); ???
```

Muchas gracias y un saludo !

Comment: De verdad que **no entiendo** la necesidad de esta pregunta, teniendo en cuenta **lo sencillo que es probarlo**. Haz una prueba y, si obtienes algún error, ahora sí, pregunta. Te sugiero leer [¿ Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿Como se añadirían punteros a instancias de B en ese vector?

- Directamente:

  ```
  punt.push_back(new B(name));
  ```
- Indirectamente:

  ```
  B *b = new B(name);
  punt.push_back(b);
  ```

> ¿Como se eliminarían esos punteros del vector?

- Directamente:

  ```
  delete punt[0];
  punt.erase(punt.begin());
  ```
- Indirectamente:

  ```
  B *b = punt[0];
  delete b;
  punt.erase(punt.begin());
  ```

---

Pero ¿sabes qué es mejor?: lo mejor es **no usar punteros en crudo**, usa punteros inteligentes:

```
using puntero_B = std::unique_ptr<B>;
std::vector<puntero_B> punt;
```

Ahora, volvamos a hacernos las preguntas:

> ¿Como se añadirían punteros a instancias de B en ese vector?

- Directamente:

  ```
  punt.emplace_back(new B(name));
  ```
- Indirectamente:

  ```
  B *b = new B(name);
  punt.emplace_back(b);
  ```

> ¿Como se eliminarían esos punteros del vector?

- Directamente:

  ```
  punt.erase(punt.begin());
  ```
- Indirectamente:

  ```
  auto &b = punt[0];
  b.reset(nullptr);
  punt.erase(punt.begin());
  ```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZJdS8MwFIavm19xqODaC8eu11qwc1NvpsgExUlI01CCbVLTZE5G/es1bYebIBYJJIf3OV@cE1qWZzQnImuaEy5oblIGIZeVVowUETpoBSuk@jhWNoxqqY4VG8VFFiFkDUM1xGiHnEqn02lPQATI@Yw9H3bQyVQaDWEIor1G9tgH47v7@Wr1hBcPy9nq5naJcUfXYhRAjeoAIS40FIQLbyN56rdFTNWmL43QTEkcw3mf3wj@ZhgutQrjKNj30vcdfjtHXZxN67TvmBVlTijDCaGvnmDvEO/cC7f2gz94PMBnA/xygM8H@GKAXw3w644jhxgtYWunt9cf3frXsK1/GJciFfM6M2GZ3Yl/qPRPtK9/mtgGWvQ8ebH@yViximlPmDy3ixxK8eNfuQsuIGU5lEpmihRkLdzWSTFtlIBJgOqm@QI)</kbd>.

Comment: ¿Por qué con punteros inteligentes usas emplace_back y no push_back? En el caso de añadir indirectamente con punteros inteligentes, ¿por qué creas un `B* b` y uno un `std::unique_ptr<B>`? Gracias.

Comment: Respecto a la primera pregunta ¿Por qué no lo pruebas en el compilador online del que paso enlace? ;) si aún tienes dudas te animo a redactar una pregunta al respecto. Respecto a la segunda pregunta, era por reflejar lo más fielmente posible la estructura de la primera parte de mi respuesta.

Comment: Vale, es por temas de eficiencia. Parece que el push_back crea un objeto temporal y luego lo copia o mueve al destino mientras que el emplace_back crea el objeto ya en el destino (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59330916/260313). De cualquier forma, el uso de emplace_back parece no ser siempre apropiado frente al uso de push_back (https://stackoverflow.com/a/36919571/260313). ¡Gracias!

Comment: No es por temas de eficiencia @rturrado , [si la clase B no tiene constructor no funcionará con `push_back`](https://tio.run/##TY1BDoIwFETX/FM0uIGFxjUgib0IqW3FRvpbS4sxBK9eqyTqaiZv8jLc2i0fGPYxbhTyIQhJGmVG7yTTLfyYltq4xz@ZJPfG/ZNkKexbgFQC94TCDNnoRVWtC8EasictSnIQ8szC4GtYagCFnmimsJiMEuVXWg@aTw@obkF21ruGti2xAZObvWNnw3jpToxfC5R3Quf8mC9lGp30wSHZp48YXw "C++ (clang) – Try It Online"), te animo a redactar una pregunta al respecto :)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> punt.push_back(newB);
> ```

La línea está bien

> ¿Como se eliminarían esos punteros del vector?

Como todos los punteros que se obtienen con `new`: usa `delete` con cada puntero.

```
for (auto p: punt)
  delete p;
```

Un buen lugar para poner esto es el destructor de `A`.

Tenga en cuenta que esto es propenso a errores. No usamos punteros simples mucho en estos días. Recomiendo leer sobre [RAII](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) y `std::unique_ptr`.